# ModalPopupExtender como fechar ao clicar fora do modal

Tags: asp.net, ajaxtoolkit

Trabalhando em um projeto legal, estou usando o `ModalPopupExtender` do `AjaxToolKit`.

Já identifiquei se posso usar os atributos `OkControlID` e `CancelControlID` para definir qual controle, um `Button` por exemplo, fecha o modal.

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
     runat="server"
     OkControlID="btnOkay"
     CancelControlID="btnCancel">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

O que gostaria de saber é se existe a possibilidade de fechar o Modal ao clicar fora da área da janela Modal que foi aberta.

Existe algum atributo ou outro código que permita fazer isso?

Comment: Ricardo, se não me engano essa biblioteca foi descontinuada. Eu não recomendaria seu uso, por experiência própria use Jquery!

Comment: É verdade, mas como é um legado, eu não gostaria de alterar muito nem substituir código, apenas fazer uma melhoria

Comment: Aqui tem uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650345/want-to-be-able-to-close-a-modal-popup-when-clicked-outside-of-it) creio que pode ser o que precisa.

Comment: @Marconi interessante, vou fazer um teste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o link do @Marconi, a solução do link do SO em inglês:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650345/want-to-be-able-to-close-a-modal-popup-when-clicked-outside-of-it

A solução proposta é adicionar um **listener** para o evento **click** do `background` que o modal exibe, e nesse caso fechar esconder o modal:

1. Setar o nome da classe do `background`:
2. Com `jQuery`, usa o evento **click**:

`jQuery('.jsMpeBackground').click(function () {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('_backgroundElement', '');
    $find(id).hide();
});`

Eu preferi mudar a linha que esconde o modal. Isso porque eu quero que a função de callback de quando o modal é fechado seja executado, então mudei essa linha:

```
$find(id).hide();
```

por essa:

```
$('#btnOkay').click();
```